# Got an Increment error "Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've got the following module:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "reputation",
    aliases: ['rep','vouch'],
    category: "misc",
    /**
     * @param {Discord.Message} message
     * @param {Array} args
     */
    async execute(message, args) {
      if (args.length >= 2) { 
          args.shift();
        reason = args.join(' ');
      }else reason = 'No reason provided';
      let member = message.mentions.members.first();
      const repmessage = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Reputation Given!")
      .setDescription(`<a:peachverify:853511481747046420> You gave a reputation to ${member} for: \`${reason}\``)
      .setFooter(`Rep ID: ${1++}`)
      .setColor("#02b2f7")
      message.channel.send(repmessage)
    },
  };
```

But whenever I try to run it I got an error:

> Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're trying to increment a number. Try to run the following snippet:

```js
console.log(1++)
```

If you want to increase the reputation of the member, you must have some variable that you can increase. I can see none in your code, so you'll need to fix that.

Anyway, once you store the reputation somewhere, you can use the `++` like you wanted:

```js
let rep = 0
console.log({ rep })
rep++
console.log({ rep })
rep++
console.log({ rep })
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, numbers are **fixed**. You cannot increment a number, but you can increment a variable.

```js
let i = 1;
console.log(i++) //shouldn’t throw
```

Doing `1++` is just like doing the following:

```js
1 = 1+1
```

Which is a clear error.